# How start the animation only when another is completed?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, each

I need to start the animation only when the other is completed? Here is what I have:

```
$( "div.line" ).each(function() {   
    $( this ).animate({
        height: "100%",
    }, 1000 );      
});
```

Comment: Check this out-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306747/jquery-how-to-make-synchronous-animations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259361/start-an-animation-when-the-other-one-is-finished-completed-in-jquery

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `.delay()`

```
$("div.line").each(function (i) {
    $(this).delay(i* 1000).animate({
        height: "100%",
    }, 1000);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/e5A7b/2/)

Comment: Why not just use the index instead of a var?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Callback like this:

```
$('.cellcontent').animate({
 height: '100%'
  },
  {
  duration: 1000,
  complete: function(){
    alert('call another animate function here');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside **[delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)**, you can also using **[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)**:

```
$( "div.line" ).each(function(i) {   
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(this).animate({
        height: "100%",
       }, 1000);
    },500 + ( i * 500 ));   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to properly use callbacks:

```
    $(function() {
    var els = $('div.line'),
            elsToAnim = els.length,
            animCounter = 0,
            animEls = function(index) {
                els.eq(index).stop().animate({
                    height: '100%'
                }, 500, function() {
                    animCounter++;
                    if (animCounter < elsToAnim) animEls(animCounter);
                });
            };

    animEls(animCounter);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4G98m/)